# IIS (There was an error while performing this operation)

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I receive `There was as error while performing this operation` error referring to web.config.    I follow below configuration:

> - OS is Windows server 2012 R2 with IIS version 8.5.
> - URL Rewrite 2.1 module is installed on the machine.
> - IIS_IUSRS has full access to the directory.
> - Application Initialization module is installed
> - .Net CLR Version v4.0.30319 and managed pipeline mode is integrated.
> - IIS configuration is as below:
> - [image]
> - [image]
>
>   Web config is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MES.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
    <!--ProjectGuid: e8701310-485f-4f88-b7d0-1473d07238ac-->
```

browsing the page I receive below message:
[image]
However, when I remove

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MES.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

from web.config I don't receive (There was as error while performing this operation) error but I get below error:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `<aspNetCore>` back and also install ASP.NET Core module on this machine, as suggested in [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

> [I also wrote a tool to better automate such detection](https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/oob-500).

Comment: IIS:ASP.NET4.5 is installed on the machine

Comment: @FaridFarzin that's useless. ASP.NET Core is completely a separate download.

Comment: What should he "add back"?

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks! I found my error: I downloaded the wrong package. One needs the **Hosting Bundle**, not just the runtime.

Comment: I had the problem same as Efrain. Should install **Hosting** Version not only runtime.

Comment: Jexus Manager is a nice tool

Answer (score 18):

[image]

This error occurred for me when trying to double-click on the Logging module for any site with a bad Web.config.

"Bad" includes Web.configs that just have a module IIS doesn't understand - in my case, IIS 10 couldn't understand the `<rewrite>` tag, and exploded with this extremely confusing error.

You can verify this by just commenting out the contents of your Web.config. The error goes away - then just gradually reduce how much is being commented out until you find the culprit, and track down that solution.

Comment: In the case of rewrites, you can install the URL rewrite module from  https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 10):

This error is typically caused by a reference inside the `web.config` which cannot be resolved by the dotNet runtime.

If you are using dotNet core, AND you installed the dotNet core hosting bundle BEFORE you configured your server to run IIS you may get this error.

To fix it in this case, you need to re-run the dotNet core hosting bundle installer AGAIN, in "repair mode"

[As described in the box entitled "Important", here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)

Comment: Hosting Bundle is installed before IIS was my exact issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with .NET Core 2.1.
I installed 2.1 SDK (v2.1.301) and as Microsoft says Hosting Bundle now installs with SDK, but in my case this did't work.
This problem disappeared only when I installed 2.1 Runtime (v2.1.1) for Hosting Bundle Installer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to install [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)
I had same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.  In my case, I was deploying a .NET Core web app.  I only needed to install the Runtime Windows Bundle.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-8.0.2-windows-hosting-bundle-installer